# How to export huge MyISAM table to InnoDB in chunks?

Tags: mysql, for-loop, innodb, myisam

I am using the MySQL Workbench to alter some huge (Millions of rows) MyISAM tables to InnoDB. I tryed it by `ALTER TABLE...` and by `INSERT INTO othertable SELECT * FROM mytable` after cloning the table but it seems that the tables are too big. The workbench quits with an error about *lost connection to server...*.

So I thought I could wright a SQL script, that loops oversy every 10000 entry or so and copy the content of the MyISAM table in chunks to the InnoDB table.

Since there seem to be no for loops SQL I wonder if someone has a suggestion how to realize this?

```
INSERT INTO `latest`.`AUTHORS` (author_id, author_name)
SELECT
`author_names`.`author_name_id`,
`author_names`.`name`
FROM `pubmap_latest`.`dblp_author_names`;
```

This is the query that I want to run in chunks. A `count(*)`-query returns 985330 rows.

Comment: An other option is too export/import your table via plain text files.

Comment: @Scorpi0: Wouldn't this take too long?

Comment: If it is a one time operation, you don't care if it will take long or not, it will work. If it is a routine job, then you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use mysqldump (command line tool) to export the data from the old table and then import it into the new table. Something like:

`mysqldump database table > file.sql`

Then edit the table name and type in the file and:

`mysql database < file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the `LIMIT` keyword in `SELECT` statements, defining how many result rows you want to display. Combining this with an offset, you can split up your table in chunks. Of course, you should use an order by clause to work on the same result set, when splitting the table up into chunks.

```
SELECT `author_names`.`author_name_id`, `author_names`.`name`
FROM `pubmap_latest`.`dblp_author_names`
ORDER BY  `author_names`.`author_name_id`
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0
INTO OUTFILE dblp_author_names_0.sql
```

For offset you have to use 10000, 20000, 30000, ...

Load your results with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
```

Refer to the [MySQL 5.1 reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html).